# Ionic Sign-up and Login with Firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have just started learning ionic. I was wondering if anyone could guide me how to implement Login and Sign-up functionality using Firebase in Ionic? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you gone through the official documentation https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication

Comment: Yikes. Let's refer to newer docs please, e.g. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 (or one of these: https://www.google.com/webhp#q=ionic%202%20with%20firebase%203)

Answer (score 0):

I created a guide detailing that exact process [here](https://javebratt.com/firebase-3-email-auth/).

But if you're just learning Ionic I do suggest you go through Ionic's documentation or invest in [Joshua Morony's Book](https://www.joshmorony.com/building-mobile-apps-with-ionic-2/). It's what I used to learn Ionic 2 before jumping into Firebase :)